# Shopware 6 Paypal Error "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID"

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Yesterday our customer got this error.

Also yesterday an order was placed with paypal as payment method. The payment status is unconfirmed.

I think, payments made through paypal should instantly become paid. Am I right?

Does anyone know, what exactly could have triggered this error?

Comment: Do you have a backtrace? Where do you see this error?

Comment: All PayPal payments are unconfirmed until a Webhook is triggered, that confirms the payment. Where did this error occur?

Comment: of course if an error occurs the payment is not instantly paid ;-) the error occurs if a PayPal ID is tried to processed which is not known to PayPal. this could e.g. happen, if you try to process a sandbox payment with your live credentials or vice-versa. 

or there is another underlying problem, but which is hard to find the cause with the few information you gave

Comment: @LastSgt this not completely correct. Not all PayPal payments need a webhook.